# Angular 2 FormControl, validation method parameter passing

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

How do we pass parameters into the validation methods we've defined for each FormControl in our Angular 2 code? For example, in below code, how do I pass a parameter into validateSalary? Normal way of writing the method like a function doesn't work

**myForm.component.ts:** 
...

```
export class myFormComponent {
...

this.thisForm= this.builder.group({
      salary: ["", ValidationService.validateSalary]
    });

... }
```

**validation.service.ts**:

```
export class ValidationService { 

   ...
   static validateSalary (control: Control, myInput: string) { ...}
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need something like this:

```
static validateSalary(myInput: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        // put your logic here
    };
}
```

Then in your Component, declare it like this:

```
this.thisForm = this.builder.group({
  salary: ["", ValidationService.validateSalary("1000.00")]
});
```

Comment: My question is that how do you pass myInput in myForm.component.ts?